# SPARQL select does not work as expected

Tags: sparql, linked-data

If I run this query

```
SELECT ?a ?b ?c ?g ?maxtrust
WHERE
{
  {
    SELECT ?a (MAX(?t) AS ?maxtrust)
    WHERE{
    GRAPH ?g { ?a a gr:productorservicemodel } 
    GRAPH <uri:trust> { ?g exepo:trust ?t}
    }
    GROUP BY ?a
  }
GRAPH ?g {?a ?b ?c}
GRAPH <uri:trust> { ?g exepo:trust ?maxtrust}
}
```

i get this response:

```
| a         | b                | c                        | g         | maxtrust |
|-----------|------------------|--------------------------|-----------|----------|
| uri:prodA | rdf:type         | gr:ProductOrServiceModel | uri:alice | 1.0      |
| uri:prodA | exe:EarCoupling  | Intraaural               | uri:alice | 1.0      |
| uri:prodA | exe:WearingStyle | In-ear                   | uri:alice | 1.0      |
| uri:prodB | rdf:type         | gr:ProductOrServiceModel | uri:bob   | 0.5      |
| uri:prodB | exe:EarCoupling  | Extraauricolare          | uri:bob   | 0.5      |
```

since I'm only interested in the relation between  `a` and  `g` I guessed that this query will have  done the trick:

```
SELECT ?a ?g
WHERE
{
  {
    SELECT ?a (MAX(?t) AS ?maxtrust)
    WHERE{
    GRAPH ?g { ?a a gr:productorservicemodel } 
    GRAPH <uri:trust> { ?g exepo:trust ?t}
    }
    GROUP BY ?a
  }
GRAPH ?g {?a ?b ?c}
GRAPH <uri:trust> { ?g exepo:trust ?maxtrust}
}
```

I would expected this result:

```
| a         | g         |
|-----------|-----------|
| uri:prodA | uri:alice |
| uri:prodA | uri:alice |
| uri:prodA | uri:alice |
| uri:prodB | uri:bob   |
| uri:prodB | uri:bob   |
```

instead I got this:

```
| a         | g         |
|-----------|-----------|
| uri:prodA | uri:alice |
| uri:prodA | uri:alice |
| uri:prodA | uri:alice |
```

What is going on? is my understanding of the SPARQL logic completely wrong?

**edit:** more info

the datasets are:

alice (`GRAPH uri:alice`):

```
uri:prodA
    a gr:ProductOrServiceModel;
    exe:EarCoupling "Intraaural"^^xsd:string ;
    exe:WearingStyle "In-ear"^^xsd:string .
```

bob (`GRAPH uri:bob`):

```
uri:prodA
    a gr:ProductOrServiceModel;
    exe:EarCoupling "Intraauricolare"^^xsd:string .
uri:prodB
    exe:WearingStyle "extraauricolare"^^xsd:string .
```

trust (`GRAPH uri:trust`):

```
uri:alice exe:trust "1.0"^^xsd:float .
uri:bob exe:trust "0.5"^^xsd:float .
```

I'm using stardog as triplestore

Comment: What will happen if you only ask for `?a`?

Comment: @Artemis I get 3 times `uri:prodA`

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataset?  Which SPARQL engine are you using?

Comment: I've updated my post with the requested info

Comment: to me this seems like a bug in the stardog sparql engine.

Answer (score 0):

if you're only interested in the relation between `?a` and `?g` your query could be much simpler:

```
select distinct ?a ?g where {
  graph ?g { ?a [] [] }
}
```

Comment: I'm interested in which graph is stored the ?a with the maximum trust, so your query is useless in my case. Sorry